# Parametrized test tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have some standalone test code (using Spock, in case it matters), which I need to pass a parameter into.

Currently, I have a minimal `build.gradle` script which takes advantage of the fact that gradle will automatically generate a `test` task, so I pass my parameter into the tests as a system property using the following clause:

```
test {
    systemProperties = [serviceName:serviceName]
}
```

With that, I can pass the parameter as a project parameter to Gradle, e.g.

```
gradle -PserviceName=SomeServiceName test
```

This does work, but I'm not too happy with it. There are only a known number of valid parameter values, so I'd like to have these pre-defined for the user, ideally as separate Gradle tasks, e.g. to be able to run:

```
gradle testSomeService
gradle testSomeOtherService
```

where in my `build.gradle` I would define these tasks to set the property to a given value and then call `test`. Is there a 'nice' way to do this?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for gradle rules: https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10FE1

Comment: rules are another way to solve this. problem with rules is that they are not as easy to restrict than explicit task creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could setup different test tasks like this:

```
["serviceA", "serviceB", "serviceC"].each{ serviceName ->
    task("${serviceName}Test", type:Test){
        group = "Service Test"
        systemProperties = [serviceName:serviceName]    
    } 
}
```

Now you have an explicit test task for each service. And these tasks are discoverable by running `gradle tasks`:

```
Service Test tasks
------------------
serviceATest
serviceBTest
serviceCTest
```

Comment: Works great - actually even more convenient, since I can read the list of services from external file. I was slightly disappointed to lose the ability to pass the service name from command line (for experimenting with services temporarily set up), but it turns out it wasn't really a viable solution anyway. Thanks!